# Create svn directory tagging using Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, tagging, jenkins-plugins

I need to tag a directory using jenkins. This is what is my need.

I have a folder xyz in a ssh server. I have checked out to jenkins directory 
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jobname/workspace

I need to tag the workspace directory in an svn location 
https://xxx.xxx.com/svn/xx/tags/xx-xx/xx-xx/${JOB_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}-${BUILD_ID}

how to do this? pleaaase help.

Comment: You might want to think about your svn structure.  there are a myriad of questions on SO, as well as some good stuff in the svn redbook.  nested tags are going to confuse any tool - and anyone that comes into your organization. generally you want to tag the whole project, and then have the tag be right under /tags.  like https://xxx.xxx.com/svn/xx/tags/${JOB_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}-${BUILD_ID}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best to do so is using the [Subversion Tagging Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Tagging+Plugin).

It allows to create a post-build action where *Tag Base URL*, *Tag Comment*, and *Tag Delete Comment* can be configured. Let's assume your workspace directory is `svn://repo/trunk`. As *Tag Base URL* you'd configure `tags/${JOB_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}-${BUILD_ID}`.

When your build completes successful SVN tagging will be automatically executed.

Comment: I am using the Subversion tagging plugin. Here I want to tag few folders before the build gets executed. In that case what should I do?

Comment: the SVN Tagging plugin allows only post-build-actions to my knowledge. So you'd probably need to split up your job into 2 jobs with a shared workspace, where the first job does do the checkout, tagging and triggers the second job which performs your build.

Comment: Thanks :) Can we pass custom parameters while tagging? instead of default variables? like JOB_NAME ?

Comment: you can, as example my default setting is `tags/lastSuccessfulBuild-${JOB_NAME}`